# How to find when train nears station?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, gps, line

I am creating an app for tracking trains. When the train comes near to a railway station the system should identify it.

To do that I want to gather GPS coordinates near the station and save them.  Then when trains send GPS coordinates to the system, it will compare saved coordinates and identify the station name ...

[image: -]

How to find all longitude and latitudes (all gps coordinates)within the line from start point to end point?

If line is short (like 100 m long) i want to find all gps points in that line, so that I can save them in a database ..

[image]

thats why i want collect gps points in  that line

Comment: As there are an infinite number of points along a line, could you please clarify what you mean?  Would you like to find the coordinates of all the vertices of a line?  Or do you want to find the coordinates of points at a given interval?  Such as every 100 metres?

Comment: yes definitely line could be 100m long how can i find it ?

Comment: Yes what? Please clarify what you need, use the edit button below your question to update it with the new information.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Quedtion to provide the clarification that @Fezter and I seek, please? Your comment has not made your Question any clearer for me.

Comment: From what I gather, you have a line layer and you have a layer containing points that were captured using GPS.  You want to get the coordinates of all the points that fall on the line layer?  Due to the inaccuracies of GPS, I doubt many if any of the points will fall exactly on your line.  You'll probably need to find the points within a given distance of that line.  Please edit your question again and give us as many details as possible.

Comment: are you clear it now?

Comment: I'm confused about why you have tags for `openlayers` and `openstreetmap` which get no mention in your Question, and then you mention that you are using a database but provide no details or tag about that.

Comment: using openlayers im going to collect coordinates ....

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you will get the GPS position of a train, and you need to figure out which station it is at.

If so, you are trying to solve it in the wrong way. You shouldn't try to save the GPS locations of all potential points, and then test the equality one by one. This isn't a good idea for the following reasons:

- Because the GPS location given by any senor has some level of error, there is very little chance that it will fall exactly on your given line.
- Secondly, even if it falls exactly on the line, there are infinitely many points on that line.

To solve this issue, you need to do some spatial operations. You need to buffer the line to some tolerance, say 25 m, and then test if the train's location falls within this buffer polygon.

Since you will have many stations in your data, it is best if you use a spatial database to do these kinds of spatial queries.

If you are using SQL Server 2008 R2, you should have a look at the following functions:

- [STBuffer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933963%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) This function can be used to create a buffer around your station (line) geometry
- [STWithin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933991%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) This function can be used to check if the input point is within the buffered Geometry.

Comment: thank you Devdatta ..... thank you a lot for helping ....

Comment: could you please tell me how to  do that you suggestion im not clear it ?

Comment: What server side technology will you be using? what database will you be using? all this details are needed before I can give you details.

Comment: Im using ASP.net Data base MS SQL Server 2008 R2 [coz its support gelocation data types]

Comment: @AmilaThennakoon: Please see my edits.

Comment: that mean i have to input  current position of the train to that functions?

Comment: @AmilaThennakoon: Correct

Comment: thank for your valuable support .... feel this is some what tough task but you give me new direction ...

Comment: though im use STBuffer() or STWithin() function i have to maintain gps data (stations gps points)in database ist it ?

Comment: No, you don't need to save the GPS location of the train in the Database; You can write a Web service, which gets the GPS location as lat and long, and then runs a SQL query and then returns if the gps location is in the buffer of the station or not.

Comment: sorry im new to this field , what is gps location buffer?, i will get the trains current position(lat,long) .to check that train in particular  train station from which data ill compare  to identify train station name ?

Comment: ohh sorry according to my understand ill save in db  at lest one gps point related to the station , when train current gps location received  ill check with 100 m gps locationd(using sql functions ) from that trains gps location ,to ensure train near  to the station .if staion gps location include withing 100m gps locations  the system will alerts . is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

The Train/Rail companies do not rely on GPS. They can use up-to 3 methods:

**Block Occupancy** detection requires the layout to be divided into individual blocks, each one isolated from the next, and the power to the block fed throgh the detector. The detector will sense any current being drawn by a train within the block

**Infra red detection** relies on a sensor module that produces an infra red beam and is able to switch state when a train is above the beam and the beam is reflected back on the sensor.

**Magnetic detection** involves fixing magnets to the bottom of trains and these activating reed switches placed at strategic points on the track

Simplest: You need to create a method of a 25m block around a train and have to detect when it left the last block and the speed it is traveling.

See
http://www.railwayblog.kevinappleby.co.uk/train-detection-and-dcc-some-armchair-musings-541/